# считывание из файла строк - возможно ошибки

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, fstream, getline

У меня есть 100 логов по 5-10ГБ, в которых записаны строки с данными

> [double]:[double]:[int]:[string]:[string]:[string]:[string]:[int]

но не в этом суть

Считываю данные следующим образом:
для каждого файла последовательно выполняю код

```
std::ifstream data;

std::string line;

while (std::getline(data, line))
{
    // обработка данных
}

data.close();
```

По отдельности файлы обрабатываются корректно, но вот когда они обрабатываются последовательно один за одним в рамках одной программы, происходит непонятное:

после ~2.900.000.000 строк (около 3 миллиардов строк) программа перестаёт считывать строки

Как я понимаю `std::getline(data, line)` сразу возвращает false

Почему может возникать такая проблема и как с ней побороться?
Программа скомпилирована как 64разрядная, везде используется __int64, long long int, т.е. никаких переполнений возникать не должно.

В Debug режиме посмотреть не могу :( программа и в Release работает долго, а уж в Debug не долждаться этой 3 миллиардной строки.

Может какой-то буфер переполняется (память не течет, вернее заметно не течет, т.е. на первый взгляд не видно) и надо его регулярно сбрасывать?

Comment: Если закомментировать обработку данных и оставить только `while (std::getline(data, line)) {}`, вылетает?

Comment: У вас файлы по окончании обработки закрываются? Может, просто слишком велико количество открытых файлов, и *очередной* файл просто не открывается?

Comment: *В Debug режиме посмотреть не могу* используйте `DebugBreak()` или `__EMIT__(0xCC);` или  `__asm { db 0xCC; };` или `__asm { int 3;}` одно из сработает. Вызов точки останова можно совместить с оператором if так, что б отловить странную ситуацию в дебагере.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849087/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1365629_849087

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса **вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям**. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса. **Вопрос лучше удалить**. (см. самоответ автора ниже)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать внутренний **log** короткого размера. Создаём класс, который будет записывать последние 12 событий, например используя **vector** , **индекс лога куда писать** . Далее записываем лог , прибавляем индекс , если он равен 12 то обнуляем. В **log** можно прописать куча инфо, номера строк , результат который выдал **getline** , результат проверки флага **eof**. Бонус короткого размера, что не будет требовать память и инфо нужно только последнее.

Answer (score 0):

В коде ранее специально поставил отладочную строчку:

```
if (filesAmount > 30)
     break;
```

Именно поэтому программа не работала...

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса **вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям**. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса. **Вопрос лучше удалить**.