# Как поставить програмную точку останова

Tags: отладка, любой-язык, faq

Как поставить програмную точку останова в разных языках средах и IDE. Часто вижу вопросы не могу отладить программу потому что программа большая, обьёмы большие. Цикл на 10000000. Такие ситуации можно отловить, например, при возникновении ошибки у меня i=357489, а не понятно почему возникло исключение, тогда делаем, напимер так:

```
 for (i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
   if (i==357489) DebugBreak();
   // код
   }
```

Но `DebugBreak` - функция windows. Как можно поставить точки останова в других средах?

Comment: Эээ, это что? Что у вас с метками? Как-то слишком общим вопрос выглядит.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под средой? Язык, ОС, IDE?

Comment: В нормальной среде (я смотрю на VS) не нужно вносить дополнительные правки в код для того чтобы поставить брейкпоинт на конкретное условие

Comment: Угу, как и в GDB. Даже CodeBlocks это умеет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP кому то удобнее средой, кому-то в коде. Особенно если условие сложное. Да и два-три слова на клавиатуре я напишу быстрее чем по среде тыкаться мышкой... хотя... Я считаю что софтовая точка останова достаточно удобная и так же заслуживает отдельного внимания.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [с](/questions/tagged/%d1%81) [с++](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b) есть такие варианты поставить точку останова

- `DebugBreak();`   - среда [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)
- `__builtin_trap()` - среда [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)
- `raise(SIGTRAP)` - работа с сигналами POSIX [posix](/questions/tagged/posix)
- `__EMIT__(0xCC)` или `__emit__(0xcc);` - некоторые среды поддерживают вставку кода
- `__asm { int 3;}` или   `__asm { db 0xCC;}`  ассемблерная вставка

Для других сред

- [с#](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%23) `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) `debugger;`
- [java](/questions/tagged/java)  `try {throw new TurnOnDebuggerException();}catch(TurnOnDebugger td) {/*Nothing*/ }`
- [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal)  `inline($CC);`
- [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) [visual-basic](/questions/tagged/visual-basic) `stop`